# Scientific Research Paper

Tags: academic-writing, research

Is it okay to reference material from a previous paragraph, like as follows "In paragraph 3" or "In the introduction"? Or do I have reassert the idea, if so does it have to require a citation again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it would be okay to reference previous paragraphs, but if you can try to put the information close to the point where you reference it to minimize paper flipping.

You could probably also just reference the idea, like 'this is possible thanks to X, which blahblahblah'. Not really linking back to another paragraph, but bringing that information of the paragraph back to the front of their minds so they know what you're talking about without telling them to flip around your report.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference it but have a specific identifier not make them count the paragraphs, which may be different by the time it is printed and all the editing and changes have happened.

You do not need another citation but do include all references about it in the index.